# strange ! operator in angular source code

Tags: angular, typescript, operators, logical-operators

Have trouble understanding the use of "!" operator in angular 4.x.x source code. It occurs quite often across some native modules but seems redundant.
Example: `this.withCredentials = requestOptions.withCredentials !;`
I also didn`t manage to run the code with "!" in my Chrome console without an exception. Can somebody clarify the meaning?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/static_request.ts
You can find the example of usage on 102, 103, 97, 78 etc. lines.